# How to Capture a View thats in front of user's eye in visionOS Programmatically

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, realitykit, visionos

I'm working on a VisionOS-based application, and I'm facing a challenge when attempting to programmatically capture the content of a view that's currently in front of the user's eyes.

I've tried using the traditional methods for capturing a view, such as using UIView.renderedImage or UIWindow snapshots. However, these approaches does not capture components in front of user's eyes.

Comment: I am pretty sure apple mentioned something to this respect when they introduced visionOS, they said something about developers not having the ability to track exactly what the user is looking at